# Singleton convention in .NET

Tags: .net, design-patterns, coding-style, singleton

Is there any convention on whether to use a property or a method when implementing a singleton pattern in .NET?

I can't think of any good reason to use one or the other, other than a method could, potentially, accept parameters in the future.

Comment: Why would you use a method?

Comment: I suppose an argument could be made for using a method if the singleton creation were a time consuming operation or could experience transient errors. Both were mentioned in the Framework Design Guidelines book as justification for preferring methods over properties. Otherwise, a property would be a more standard approach for singletons I would think. Read [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx) for more details.

Comment: @BrianGideon From the first line _"In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data"_.  So... for the majority of it's life it's just data, but the initial instantiation has side affects.  Given that, it should _probably_ be a method.

Comment: @BanksySan: I think as long the initial creation isn't time consuming or could suffer transient errors (like from an external resource) then I'd still lean towards a property despite the side effects argument. I know...tough call.

Comment: @BrianGideon In this case it's creating a database client, though the question was more about a theoretical 'best practice'.  It seems overly pedantic to make it a method based on that, but then, we are software engineers for a reason and it's not out social skills.  It _feels_ like there should be a solution out there that fits in with best practice perfectly.

Comment: @BanksySan: If you only knew how much time I spend on simply naming properties/methods...so yeah, I get the pedantic part. I am the epitome of pedantic :)

Answer (score 2):

The article [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has some good recommendations for general purpose scenarios. The problem is that lazy initialization clouds the topic a bit.

On one hand you have these arguments that suggest it could be a property.

- A singleton is just a piece of data.
- Lazy initialization does not qualify as an observable side effect. They keyword here being "observable". In other words, the fact that the singleton was created just now or was already created is encapsulated from the caller's perspective.

On the other hand you have these arguments that suggest it could be a method.

- A singleton that requires complex initialization could be time consuming. Generally speaking time consuming operations are implemented as methods.
- If the singleton creation could throw exceptions of a transient nature (database connection, file operations over the network, etc.) then some callers might appreciate it better if a method were used instead.

I have seen singletons implemented both ways. In the end your decision will not have a huge impact on the rest of your application so it might be a moot discussion. Then again, if this were part of a public API you are exposing then the decision does have some importance. The main thing is to think about how callers will react to your decision. For example, most developers assume (unconsciously usually) that properties are exception-free so if your singleton creation could throw then maybe it is better to have a `GetInstance()` method. Otherwise, having an `Instance` property would probably be the better route.

Another thing to consider is whether the singleton will be used in XAML bindings for WPF or Silverlight. Typically you bind public properties to the XAML elements so in this case implementing your singleton as a property would be a better route despite the arguments for the method approach.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a best practice of having an `Initialise()' method in the app startup or the DI, then accessing the created object would be a property.

Answer (score 1):

In general, most "standardized" examples of a Singleton use a property, with the underlying instance created via `Lazy<T>`.

Given that a singleton is typically just returning an instance, a (get only) property matches the expectation well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property due to the two **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)** reasons:-

> This implementation has two main advantages:
>
> - Because the instance is created inside the Instance property method,    the class can exercise additional functionality (for
>     example,    instantiating a subclass), even though it may introduce
>     unwelcome    dependencies.
> - The instantiation is not performed until an object asks for an    instance; this approach is >referred to as lazy instantiation. Lazy instantiation avoids instantiating unnecessary singletons when >the application starts.

Comment: These would also work with a method, by the way.  This is really the reasons to use a property over a *field*, not a *method*.